# Javascript RegEx positive lookahead not working as expected

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

First of all i am not very good in dealing with regex But I am trying to create a regex to match specific string while replace it by skipping first character of matcher string using positive look ahead. Please see detail below

Test String  `asdf.wakawaka asdf.waka df.waka [df.waka (df.waka _df.waka {df,waka`

RegEx  `(?=[^\w])df\.`

Replacement String  `kkk.`

Expected Result  `asdf.wakawaka asdf.waka kkk.waka [kkk.waka (kkk.waka _df.waka {df,waka`

But regex above dos not found any match thus it replaces nothing as a result and give original test string in the result.

Without positive lookahead (skip first character strategy) it matches my requirement. see [matching regex sample on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/efjzQk/1)

With positive lookahead giving unexpected results [regex with positive look aheah on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/efjzQk/2)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Like [THIS](https://regex101.com/r/efjzQk/3)?

Comment: Right @Gurman, this is exactly what i missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `[^\w]` means you want to match and consume a char other than a word char before the match you need to replace.

However, this char is *consumed* and you cannot restore it without capturing it first. You might use Gurman's approach to match `/(^|\W)df\./g` and replace with `'$1kkk.`, but you may also use a word boundary:

```
\bdf\.
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/efjzQk/4)

JS demo:

```js
var s = "asdf.wakawaka asdf.waka df.waka [df.waka (df.waka _df.waka {df,waka";
console.log(
  s.replace(/\bdf\./g, 'kkk.')
);
```

However, if you do not want to replace `df.` at the start of the string, use

```js
var s = "df. asdf.wakawaka asdf.waka df.waka [df.waka (df.waka _df.waka {df,waka";
console.log(
  s.replace(/(\W)df\./g, '$1kkk.')
);
```

Comment: This explains why i can't get my regex working. I am accepting the answer as it resolve the problem.